# Type Error on Backbone/Marionette Single Model Fetch

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I am getting used to using Backbone and Marionette and run into a little snag that I am sure I am overlooking something.  I am trying to populate my ItemView with a model from my API and I can see the request and data coming back ok but I get a Type Error:obj is undefined in what appears to be my listener:

```
TypeError: obj is undefined
var id = obj._listenerId || (obj._listenerId = _.uniqueId('l'));
```

Here is my Model/View

```
var MyDetailView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: '#my-item-detail',
    initialize: function () {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
        // bind the model change to re-render this view
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
    },
    tagName: "div"
})

var MyModel= Backbone.Model.extend({ urlRoot: '/api/model', intialize: function () { } });
```

And my code to execute:

```
var m = new MyModel({ id: 123});
        m.fetch({
            success: function (model, response) {
                var view = new MyDetailView (model);
                  layout.content.show(view);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to pass the model in as an options hash and not just the first parameter to MyDetailView like so:

```
var view = new MyDetailView({ model: model });
```

Also for future reference Marionette does _.bindAll with render in the Marionette.View constructor.

Comment: d'oh!  Thanks, this did it.  Thanks for the response!